# cannot compile c++ programs with input and output in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

Whenever I try to build C++ programs that involve I/O, I get errors in Eclipse.

```
02:19:02 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project SecondProject ****
make all 
Building target: SecondProject
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "SecondProject"   
g++: fatal error: no input files
makefile:45: recipe for target 'SecondProject' failed
compilation terminated.
make: *** [SecondProject] Error 1
```

It compiles just fine for other C++ programs that don't require user input.

However, I can compile just fine when I use the command line without an issue. Why is this happening? Is there a fix for it?

Comment: Nothing to do with user input, you don't have any source file, it's the problem

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is attempting to compile SecondProject with no source files. Which is why you observed this:

```
g++  -o "SecondProject"   
g++: fatal error: no input files
```

**Troubleshoot**

Verify your project properties in

> Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols

Check that your `Source Location` and `Include` paths are setup correctly. If your paths are correct, you should see something like when you build again:

```
g++  -o "SecondProject"   ./<your src folder>/<something>.o ...
```

Otherwise, create a fresh new C/C++ Project and add the sources again.

Comment: I do have source files though.

Comment: Okay oops it's because I had Clang and Clang++ as my C and C++ compilers in my toolchain...but I don't see why that makes a difference.

Comment: @Glassjawed The compiler is attempting to build **without** any source file, as a result showing the "fatal error: no input files" message. You need to tell the IDE where to find the sources else it will not generate a proper make file for the build.